# Does Eddystone have any SDK for with ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework, eddystone

I am looking for an Eddystone SDK that can work with Ionic framework. Let me know if anyone of the community member have any idea about it.

Answer (score 2):

This GitHub project should work with Ionic
https://github.com/evothings/cordova-eddystone

Here is another Cordova build
https://evothings.com/detecting-eddystone-beacons-in-javascript-made-easy/

Please post any other info you gathered since posting, as I am looking to integrate this into an Ionic app myself. I have purchased the Avvel X Beacon for testing from Amazon

Comment: I've never managed to make evothing's plugin work. I opened an issue in May without success..

Answer (score 1):

I was just wondering the same and I came across this:

http://market.ionic.io/starters/proximiio-ionic-demo-app

I've not had an opportunity to test it yet though as I don't have any hardware.